# Bash check environment variables are set in an array of env vars

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have an array of environment variables, and want to check each env var to ensure they are set. I'm trying to use an array b/c I'm going to have around 30 env vars to check. If I don't use the for loop and only the if statement, the script works. Unfortunately, I don't want 30 separate if statements.

Am I going about this the wrong way?

```
# my array to store env vars
env_vars=("A" "B" "C")

export A=10
export B=test
export C=

for each in ${env_vars[@]}; do 
    echo $each # this works fine
    if [ -z "$each" ]; then # this line doesn't seem to work
        echo $each;
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

Comment: Do you mean to do `[ -z "$each" ]`, or do you mean `[ -n "$each" ]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`bash` has an operator for this: `-v`. (I'm ignoring the distinction between environment variables and shell variables for the moment.)

```
for each in "${env_vars[@]}"; do
    if ! [[ -v $each ]]; then
        echo "$each is not defined"
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

Your `[ -z "$each" ]` is just testing if the *value* of `$each` (that is, the name of the variable stored in `env_var`) is empty, which it clearly is not; it was just assigned a name! You want to see if the variable *named* in `each` is defined, which is what `-v` is for.

Without support for `-v`, you can use the following construct:

```
for each in "${env_vars[@]}"; do
    if [ -z "${!each+x}" ]; then
        echo "$each is not defined"
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

---

However, there is something to be said for *some* repetition, when it makes your code clearer. Something like

```
: ${A?A not set}
: ${B?B not set}
: ${C?C not set}
```

will work in any POSIX shell and is more straightforward than a loop requiring `bash` extensions like indirection parameter expansion or the `-v` operator.

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error. Complains about the `if ! [[ -v $each ]]; then` line. `conditional binary operator expected`. bash --version on my mac is: GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15) Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: Why is your question tagged `linux` if you are using macOS, which ships with a ridiculously old version of `bash`? `-v` requires `bash` 4 or later.

Comment: I will be deploying to `linux` and I won't have control over the version of bash.

Comment: The operating system is less important than the version of `bash` installed on that operating system. Are you even sure you'll *have* `bash`?

Comment: Yes, will def have `bash`.